# How to measure gitlab-ci resource (RAM, CPU, etc.) consumption for jobs?

Tags: docker, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my gitlab-ci.yaml I have multiple jobs like:

- assembleDebug
- assembleRelease
- uploadToStore
- release

which have approximately following form:

```
assembleRelease:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  tags:
    - a_tag
  before_script:
    - *script_1
    - *script_2
    - *script_3
  script:
    - do stuff
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./releasebundle
```

etc.

Is there a way to add a `before_script` or `script` or any flag to measure the resources consumed for each of these jobs?

I would like to print for each of these jobs some `echo` like:

```
"12 GB RAM, 78% CPU 1, 44% CPU 2, process time 34 sec., 2 GB memory"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically need to come up with a customized solution.
Tools of choice could be;

- htop, top, ps
- time
- du, dh

CPU measurements are the complicated part. Usually, it is worth looking at specific processes. This depends on what your jobs are doing. For instance, looking at large builds, I would first analyze the names of compiler processes that are running on a machine. Then I can capture the same using htop or similar.
However, when designing this, be careful to not overload the machine with the data collection and be careful with tools like du. Consider taking values at the start and and the end and get the difference.